# Web Api doesn't return exceptions

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web Api implementation (version 2.2) that doesn't throw any errors in the test environment.

If I run this method in dev

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Fail()
{
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "I shall fail", new Exception("Exception message"));
}
```

It returns as supposed

[image]

In the other environment I only get

```
{"Message":"I shall fail"}
```

Any ideas where to start looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the `IncludeErrorDetailPolicy` who was set to `Localonly`